# Print List in Reverse: TCL

Tags: tcl, reverse, expect

I am reading "Exploring Expect: A TCL-Based Toolkit ... " by Don Libes.

An end of chapter question asked to "Write a procedure to reverse a string. If you wrote an iterative solution, now write a recursive solution or vice versa."

Reading up to this point in time, I decided to try the following:

```
set list {a b c d e f g}


for {set index [expr [llength $list]-1]} {$index>=0} {incr $index - 1} {

for {set i [expr [llength $list]-1]} {$i>=0} {incr $i - 1} {

    puts [lindex $list $index]

}

}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error(s), warning(s):
wrong # args: should be "incr varName ?increment?"
    while executing
"incr $i - 1"
    ("for" body line 3)
    invoked from within
"for {set index [expr [llength $list]-1]} {$index>=0} {incr $index - 1} {

for {set i [expr [llength $list]-1]} {$i>=0} {incr $i - 1} {

    puts [lind..."
    (file "source_file.tcl" line 4)
g
```

I see that I am not incrimenting the "index" variable correctly though I am unsure as to why.
Also, is this approach recursive or iterative?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

---

________SOLUTION____________________________________

Based on the solution/approach provided by @glenn the correct code is as follows:

```
set list {a b c d e f g}



for {set i [expr {[llength $list]-1}]} {$i>=0} {incr i -1} {

    puts [lindex $list $i]

}
```

Many other examples are shown by his post below.

Comment: why do you have 2 for loops?

Comment: FWIW, reversing a string is a built-in these days: `string reverse`. Similarly, reversing a list is `lreverse`. Still, it's a good exercise to try to do it by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you are passing 3 arguments to incr: `$index`, `-` and `1`. As the error message indicates, incr takes a maximum of 2 arguments. Specify "minus 1" as `-1` with no spaces.

Take careful note of the error message:

```
wrong # args: should be "incr varName ?increment?"
```

Note how it says `varName` -- when you use `$index` you are passing the variable's *value* not the *name*. Remove the `$`

```
for {set i [expr {[llength $list]-1}]} {$i>=0} {incr i -1} {
# .................................................. ^ ^^
#                                              varname increment
```

Note the braces around the argument to expr: that's a good habit to get into.

Comment: Thank you kindly!! This helped greatly. I will now review your first post. Btw, I have modified the code to be: 

`set list {a b c d e f g}



for {set i [expr {[llength $list]-1}]} {$i>=0} {incr i -1} {

    puts [lindex $list $i]
    
}`

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few different implementations of [`lreverse`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lreverse.htm)

1. recursive

   ```
   proc lreverse_rec {list} {
       if {[llength $list] == 0} return
       set procname [lindex [info level 0] 0]
       return [concat [lindex $list end] [$procname [lrange $list 0 end-1]]]
   }
   ```
2. tail recursive

   ```
   proc lreverse_tail {list {result {}}} {
       if {[llength $list] == 0} {return $result}
       lappend result [lindex $list end]
       set procname [lindex [info level 0] 0]
       tailcall $procname [lrange $list 0 end-1] $result
   }
   ```
3. while loop a (from a [very old discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/UYwuw7ADCn8) of this very topic)

   ```
   proc lreverse_while_a {xlist} {
       set rlist $xlist
       for {
           set j 0
           set i [expr {[llength $xlist]-1}]
       } {$i>=0} {
           incr i -1
           incr j
       } {
           set rlist [lreplace $rlist[set rlist {}] $j $j [lindex $xlist $i]]
       }
       set rlist
   }
   ```
4. while loop b

   ```
   proc lreverse_while_b {list} {
       set result {}
       while {[llength $list]} {
           lappend result [lindex $list end]
           set list [lrange $list[set list {}] 0 end-1]
       }
       return $result
   }
   ```
5. while loop, but with some convenience list-op procs

   ```
   proc pop {listVar} {
       upvar 1 $listVar list
       set result [lindex $list end]
       set list [lrange $list[set list {}] 0 end-1]
       return $result
   }
   proc push {listVar value} {
       upvar 1 $listVar list
       lappend list $value
   }
   proc shift {listVar} {
       upvar 1 $listVar list
       set result [lindex $list 0]
       set list [lrange $list[set list {}] 1 end]
       return $result
   }
   proc unshift {listVar value} {
       upvar 1 $listVar list
       set list [linsert $list[set list {}] 0 $value]
   }
   ```

   which all lead to this tidy solution

   ```
   proc lreverse_listops {list} {
       set result {}
       while {[llength $list]} {push result [pop list]}
       return $result
   }
   ```

I can't lay my hands on a web page explaining the `set list [... $list[set list {}] ...]` idiom, but it's an optimization for the Tcl internals when you're mutating a value. UPDATE: here it is: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/K (thanks mrcalvin)

---

And some benchmarking

```
## put all the above procedures here ...

proc main {} {
    set list [list]
    for {set i 0} {$i <= 100} {incr i} {lappend list $i}
    foreach proc {
        lreverse_rec
        lreverse_tail
        lreverse_while_a
        lreverse_while_b
        lreverse_listops
    } {
        puts [format "%-20s %s" $proc [time [list $proc $list] 1000]]
    }
}

main
```

outputs something like

```
lreverse_rec         271.029 microseconds per iteration
lreverse_tail        293.496 microseconds per iteration
lreverse_while_a     75.541 microseconds per iteration
lreverse_while_b     53.962 microseconds per iteration
lreverse_listops     247.262 microseconds per iteration
```

Comment: The recommendation is to write `$list[set list {}]` rather than `$list[unset list]`. The objective is identical, but using `set` is more performant than `unset`. See "Unsharing Objects" in https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/K.